# Why conversion from char* to std::string is more preferred than to const char* in the snippet?

Tags: c++, string, boost, type-conversion

I was learning boost's **variant** and found that it makes implicit conversion from `char*` to `std::string` in this snippet:

```
boost::variant<int, char*, std::string> v;
// implicitly converted from char* to std::string, so we can't store char* and std::string both?
v = "123";
std::cout << "boost::variant value: " << boost::get<std::string>(v) << std::endl;
v = 1;
std::cout << "boost::variant value: " << boost::get<int>(v) << std::endl;
v = "123";
std::cout << "boost::variant value: " << boost::get<char*>(v) << std::endl;
```

So the exception will be raised by the `boost::get<char*>(v)` call. I wondered a bit and tried to make it more fair: change `char*` to `const char*` in the typename list:

```
boost::variant<int, const char*, std::string> v;
v = "123";
std::cout << "boost::variant value: " << boost::get<std::string>(v) << std::endl;
```

Now exception is correct. But my question is: why compiler/library chooses `std::string` instead of `char*` as I specified? I understand, that `v = "123"` is assignment of `const char*` but why it converts to `std::string` and not `char*`?

Comment: Why do people insist on adding the c tag to questions that have nothing to do with C?

Comment: Well, sorry, I was pointing at "c++" first but it added "c". Next I forgot to remove it.

Comment: If that is a reproducible problem (if you can describe the exact steps you took to add the c++ tag, and where the c tag got added by the system instead), I encourage you do report it as a bug. It's never happened to me, and I can't manage to even make c and c++ both show up at the same time in the tag selection, but I won't rule out the possibility of you doing something I haven't thought of trying.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't remember already what I did exactly but I remember I was pointing at "c++", but maybe I also I did something else in the moment (click, key press, etc).. Okay, if I will reproduce it I'll do what you suggested to me. I also did not mean to put "c" tag here but now I think about - why not? The question is about c-type conversion between `char*` and `const char*`, is not it?

Comment: No, C and C++ are different languages, and even for the types that exist in both languages, the conversions between those types are different in C++ than they are in C. If C did have an implicit conversion from `const char *` to `char *` (it doesn't, luckily), that would have no impact on C++. If C makes `"123"` a `char[4]` rather than `const char[4]` (it does, unfortunately), that too has no impact on C++ and is not relevant to your question.

Comment: Okay, very much thanks for the explanation you have just did. I've upvoted your answer also for that :)

Comment: Your title precisely inverts the situation. Of course conversion from `char const *` to `std::string` is preferred over conversion to `char*`. Moreover, it's actually a conversion from `char const (&)[4]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const char *` doesn't implicitly convert to `char *` because that would be unsafe. The whole point of `const` is that you don't inadvertently attempt to modify the object. Suppose that `const char *` did implicitly convert to `char *`. Then what's preventing programs such as these:

```
#include <cstdio>
void f(char *s) { *s = 'a'; }
int main() { const char *str = "Hello!"; f(str); std::puts(str); }
```

which are obviously a massive error, from compiling without even so much as a warning?

Answer (score 1):

Because there's an explicit conversion from `const char *` to `std::string` from `std::string` and dropping `const` is never done implicitly for obvious reasons.